# How to use \mylabel in a \frametitle

Tags: beamer

I need to refer in `\frametitle` to a section that I have labelled with a new command `\mylabel`. Here is the code

```
\documentclass{beamer} 


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mylabel}[2]{%
\@bsphack
\begingroup
\def\@currentlabel{#2}%
\label{#1}%
\endgroup
\@esphack

}
\makeatother


\begin{document}



\section[Title 1]{This is a long title that gos on very long long long long long  
 long long title more long long }{\mylabel{LabelTopic1}{This is a long title that  
 gos on very long long long long long long long title more long long }}



\frame<presentation>{\frametitle{\ref{LabelTopic1}}}




\end{document}
```

This is what I have got 
[image]

The problem is that the name is too long and does not fit in one line of frametitle and the line does not break. I think that something is missing in the command `\mylabel`. But I don't know what.

Thank you for any help

Comment: I've tried \protect. But it doesn't work. Thank you anyhow.

Comment: I am bit niave. I have understood to do the following  '    \section[Title 1]{This is a long title that gos on very long long long long long  
 long long title more long long }{\mylabel{LabelTopic1}{This is a long title that  
 gos on very long long long long long long long title more long long }}

Comment: I really don't understant. But with me it doesn't work. I am using miktex 2.9. But I don't think that is the problem. It must be somethingelse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title and section names are what is known as moving arguments and the macros inside them should be protected from bad omen and Dutch weather. (Extra reading if interested : [Why use \DeclareTextFontCommand vs. just \newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47259/why-use-declaretextfontcommand-vs-just-newcommand)) Compile it twice

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mylabel}[2]{%
\@bsphack%
\begingroup%
\def\@currentlabel{#2}%
\label{#1}%
\endgroup%
\@esphack%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section[Title 1]{This is a long title that gos on very long long long
                  long long long long title more long long }{% Watch the next line
                      \protect\mylabel{LabelTopic1}{This is a long title that gos on very 
                      long long long long long long long title more long long}%
                      }

\frame<presentation>{\frametitle{\ref{LabelTopic1}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands might also be useful 'extra reading' to link to.

Comment: @Adam Yes that's included in David's answer

Comment: Thank you. The reading were indeed intersting. At the end I got it. I had to use XeLaTex or LuaLaTex (not Latex), which allow me to use robust commands (at least I think to have understood).