# How to create another styling format like \emph

Tags: macros

I read how to change `\emph` and changed it to `\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\bfseries}`.

Now I want to *create* another command like `\secondstyleformat` which I can configure aswell. Such a format could be bold and italic. After writing the document I could change it easily to for example italic and blue. *How can I do that?*

Comment: A number in a `LaTeX` command does not work, so `\emph2` is a syntax error. Try `\BetterEmph` or something similar

Comment: You could teach `\emph` to look for the next token and, if it finds a `2` then use `\itshape` and, otherwise, `\bfseries`… But, why wouldn't you use a *semantic* command? What are you going to *emphasize* with this “`\emph2`”.

Comment: It's not about calling it \emph2. I just want to have another styling format that I can change in the preamble.

Comment: I find it strange, why `emph` changes font style to `\bfseries`, but ok... You can declare your font style commands with `\newcommand{\OtherFontMarkup}{\itshape}` or use `\DeclareTextFontCommand, if necessary, I do not get what the issue might be

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command/macro name cannot include numbers and symbols](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66666/command-macro-name-cannot-include-numbers-and-symbols)

Comment: In my opinion it's better to be able to change your formating afterwards. For example if I come across that italic doesn't look nice I want to be able to change it bold for example. but if I have written the text with \textit{} then I will have to change every single italic phrase in the text. But for example, I can change \emph in the preamble by \DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{...}.

Comment: @user50224 So, what's the problem? If you are not going to use `\emph` and this `\emph2` at the same time, what's the inconvenience of just changing the definition of `\emph`?

Comment: @Manuel: I would not redefine the standard command `\emph` anyway. Better use logical markup, say for some text, which should be formated in special way, at first `\textit{foo}` and later on the decision to make in blue color and bold, it is better do use a command `\newcommand{\makeitboldandcoloured}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}}`, in the preamble, so you can 1st easily detect and replace such markup to change the name or change the color etc, if needed. This requires a little categorization how certain text is to be formatted

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: That's exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm not recommending to redefine it: since he already did, I'm just asking to clarify what's his real problem… But you seem to have solved the “un-question” :P

Comment: @Manuel: Sorry, I misunderstood you.

Comment: @Manuel: I just wanted to create a formatting style like Christian's `\makeitboldandcoloured`

Comment: @user50224: Please edit your post and make it clear, since I sense a presence, I have not sensed a long time ago ... the close voting force ;-)

Comment: @user50224 You can use the same system you said at first: `\DeclareTextFontCommand\makeitboldandcoloured{\bfseries\color{blue}}`.

Comment: @Manuel: Yes, it is even better to use `\DeclareTextFontCommand` instead of my proposition via `\newcommand`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47259/why-use-declaretextfontcommand-vs-just-newcommand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from doing

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand\makeitboldandcoloured{\bfseries\color{blue}}
```