# XCharter. Proper alignment of superscripts with option [sups]

Tags: fonts, superscripts

With `\usepackage[sups]{XCharter}`, when I have two references separated by a comma after the same word, I can't typeset the comma in the same style as the reference marks: `\textsuperscrip{,}` places it too high, while `\textsu{}` only works for numbers. I've tried to dig `XCharter.sty` to find a definition of `\textsu` and change it but I haven't found anything (at least not anything that seemed to give some sort of vertical spacing instruction. I'm not good at code digging, though...)

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sups]{XCharter}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Some text\footnote{First}\textsuperscript{,}\footnote{Second}\\
Some text\footnote{Third}\textsu{,}\footnote{Fourth}
\end{document}
```

Spits out

[image]

---

[EDIT]

I've decided to raise the numbers typeset by `\textsu` instead of lowering those set by `\textsuperscript`, but keeping the nice superscript figures provided by `XCharter`. I need this to work with

1) `\textsu` itself; I've settled for

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\vecchiotextsu\textsu% see tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro
\renewcommand{\textsu}[1]
    {\vecchiotextsu{\raisebox{0.28ex}{#1}}}
```

2) `endnote`

```
\renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\textsu{\theenmark}}
```

3) `\footnote`

```
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\@makefnmark}
        {\raisebox{0.28ex}{\sufigures \@thefnmark}}
\makeatother
```

So this basically answers my question.

Comment: The `\textsu` command chooses a variant of the Charter font, where the digits are superscripted, but no other character is.

Comment: Ciao egreg, thanks :-) I had the suspect. So I guess `\raisebox` is the way...

Comment: `\newcommand*{\textsup}[1]{\raisebox{-1pt}{\textsuperscript{#1}}}` seems to do the job.

Answer (score 3):

The font selected when `\textsu` is called has only the digits as superscripts and no other character.

Here's my proposal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sups]{XCharter}

\newcommand{\commasup}{%
  \textsuperscript{\kern-0.11111em \raisebox{-\height}{,}}%
}


\begin{document}

Some text\footnote{First}\commasup\footnote{Second}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using a command has the advantage that, if you decide to use a different font, the definition can be easily adjusted and the document needs no other change.

Comment: Thanks again :-) I don't understand, in `-\height`, it is minus what height? Anyway, I resolved to shift up the numbers instead... I overcomplicate for exercise, I'm going to try by myself first. I'll update in the comments.

Comment: @ArchStanton `\height` refers to the height of the material to be raised.

Comment: I'm not sure I got this right. `\height` assumes the value of the height (above the baseline of the superscripts) of the glyph inside the braces, so you basically remove that space moving it back to the baseline. Is it correct?

Comment: @ArchStanton `\height` refers to the height of the comma in scriptsize (because the font size has already been chosen); it has nothing to do with the fact we're in a superscript, that will be done later. The raising of lowering is done with respect to the baseline of the superscript.

Comment: Hi egreg, I've edited the question, have you got any suggestions? (Well that's a question that sounds silly, asked to you.) The recursive redefinition is farina del tuo sacco, I admit I don't understand it at all but I'm going to read [the tutorial](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb09-1/tb20bechtolsheim.pdf) and remedy asap. Thanks for all the help, not only when answering directly to me of course :-)

Comment: @ArchStanton I don't understand why doing that. And an explicit 1.25pt is surely bad, as it will not work in other font sizes.

Comment: You're right about the 1.25pts, I'll redefine it, thanks. I'm doing it because I think it looks better, but mostly to learn something in the process.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why raising the superscript figures just to get a worse result. Anyway, you get much better code with `\DeclareRobustCommand{\textsu}[1]{\begingroup\sufigures\raisebox{0.26ex}{#1}\endgroup}`

Comment: Those defined by `XCharter` in my opinion are too low, they get too much in the way. Thanks for the code!

Comment: I've found a way to shift the endnotes marks. Now I think it looks better... Not worth it for the aesthetics alone, sure thing. Your robust definition doesn't work (or I use it wrongly. I've placed it right after `\usepackage[sups]{XCharter}`): I get a undefined control sequence error. Why robust? I know something about robust vs fragile, I don't understand why you define it as robust.

Comment: Found: "With \DeclareTextFontCommand you get a robust command that will remain untouched when found in a moving argument such as a section title or a caption." http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47259/35903

Comment: @ArchStanton It's not really likely that `\textsu` ends up in some moving argument, but consistency is better. Since the default definition is robust, it's better to keep it such.

Comment: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\textsu}[1]{{\sufigures\raisebox{0.26ex}{#1}}}` works. I tried to use it in a section heading and I get a `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]` error. Not an issue, just another "Why?!" for the collection.

Comment: I've tried `\LetLtxMacro` for the redefinition of `\textsu`. It works on section headings with the optional toc entry so.. I think it's good.